# Reading values from the memory block which created/mofied malloc realloc?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

As I ask how can I read values from the memory which was put into a memory block by malloc/realloc?

I have a program which creates 2 memory blocks at first and extends until reach 32.Its working fine but in order not to lose values after realloc I start my scanf session with an integer called koru.Koru starts with 0 at the beginning and in every realloc I make its number half of the total amount of memory so I expect not to lose the values entered before realloc sessions but now I need to read what I wrote the memory so I will be sure that I didnt overwrite how can I do that ?

```
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "stdlib.h"
    int main()
    {
      int size=2;
      int* p1;
      int* p2;
      int n;
      p1=(int *)malloc((size*sizeof(int)));
      int b=0;
      int i=0;
      int koru=0;   
      while(size<32) 
 { 
    if(i<size){           
    for(i=koru;i<size;i++)
 {      
    printf("\nEnter value:");
    scanf("%d",p1);
     }
     }
    else if(boyut=i)         
     {  
        size=size*2;    
        p2 = (int*) realloc (p1,size*sizeof(int));
        p1=p2;  
        koru=size/2;
        printf("\nNOt enough size we make it %d also we protect %d that amount of memory"size,koru);
     }
    }    
    return 0;
    }
```

I thought putting a array[i]=p1; and reading it after while loop will solve the problem but later I figured out that its cheating I am not reading from the memory block just reading from another array so this wont work too can somebody lead the way for me please ?

What my program does:

2 blocks memory malloc
takes values and fills it
When it fills improves the memory size multiplying by 2 realloc
starts reading from half number so it dont rewite
continues this progress until it reaches 32

Edit:Simplified question:

I put lots of values in the memory after while loop how can I read them ?

I tried to read it like this but all I get is 0

```
int counter =0;
while (counter<koru)
{
printf("\n%d",p1[counter]);
counter++;
}
  return 0;
}
```

The correct code which creates a memory block with malloc and extends it with realloc after 32 it exits while loop and writes everything from the p1 pointer(from memory) thanks for help.

Working Code below:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
int main()
{
  int boyut=2;
  int* p1;
  int* p2;
  int n;
  p1=(int *)malloc((boyut*sizeof(int)));

  int b=0;
  int i=0;
  int koru=0;

while(boyut<16)
    {
    if(i<boyut){          
        for(i=koru;i<boyut;i++){    
          printf("\nDeğer Girin:");
        scanf("%d", &p1[i]);
     }
}
    else if(boyut=i)        
    {   
     boyut=boyut*2;    
     p2 = (int*) realloc (p1,boyut*sizeof(int));
     p1=p2;   
     koru=boyut/2;
     printf("\nBoyut yetersiz yeni boyutu %d yapıyoruz önceki %d kadar alanı korumaya aldık",boyut,koru);
 }
}
int counter =0;
while (counter<koru)
{
printf("\n%d",p1[counter]);
counter++;
}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format the code, this looks bad!

Comment: I will convert my values to english hold on a second.

Comment: please check the new code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking here, but to access the values in the memory, just use p1 as an array.  p1[3] would give you the 4th integer in the memory block.

Just be sure to respect the array bounds.

Comment: printf(%d,p1[3]); outputs 0 zero is it working or Am I doing a mistake ?

Comment: if I can read from p1[0-32] my problem will be solved but its giving me an error when I compile please help

Comment: This is the problem:   scanf("%d",p1);  You need to scanf into a pointer to an integer, then assign it to a slot in p1.  Alternatively, scanf("%d", &p1[i]);

Comment: scanf("%d", &p1[i]); thats what I want now my testing code works too thank you soo much.

Answer (score 1):

Bonus problem: you're not even filling the array, you're overwriting the first element each time you input.

The simple solution is to remove `p2` entirely and treat `p1` as an array:

```
...
    scanf("%d", &p1[i]);
...
```

Then to read:

```
int n;
for (n=0; n<i; n++)
    printf("%d ", p1[n]);
```

---

However, if you want to do it with two pointers instead of array indexing, you need one pointer to track the whole array for `malloc` and `realloc`, and the other to track where the current value is for reading/writing.

Initially the array is empty, so they are the same:

```
p1 = (int *)malloc(boyut * sizeof(int));
p2 = p1;
...
```

Input *only* uses the read/write pointer, and increments it each time:

```
...
    scanf("%d", p2++);
...
```

Memory management *only* uses the "base" pointer

```
...
    p1 = (int *)realloc(p1, boyut * sizeof(int));
...
```

(note you should strictly use a temporary variable for the return value of `realloc()` to check for failure, otherwise you could lose the value of `p1`)

Then to read we reset the read/write pointer to the start, and iterate through:

```
int n;
p2 = p1;
for (n=0; n<i; n++)
    printf("%d ", *p2++);
```

Comment: What but my testing code below gives me the all numbers I input (after putting scanf("%d", &p1[i]);) so how can I "overwriting the first element each time you input." ? Its working now :D

Comment: @BugraSezer the original code: `scanf("%d", p1)` always overwrites the value at `p1`, which always points to the start of the array. It's hardly surprising that it works _after changing that line to something that does the right thing_ ;) In my defence, when I started typing this the edit and other comments weren't there. I'm slow.

Comment: of course of course it overwrites I agree with you the correct one is above but thanks anyway I give you point too...